# EF Core Include translates to SQL with sub queries that have no filters

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

```
Meetings
  .Include(a => a.Document)
  .Include(a => a.Plan)
  .Include(a => a.User)
  .Include(a => a.Topics).ThenInclude(e => e.Extra)
  .Include(a => a.Components).ThenInclude(g => g.Extra)
  .Include(a => a.Recipients).ThenInclude(i => i.Info)
  .Single(a => a.MeetingId == 1)
```

The above LINQ will translate to SQLs with sub queries that have no filters:

```
SELECT [blah]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(2) [blah]
    FROM [Meeting] AS [m]
    LEFT JOIN [Plan] AS [s] ON [m].[PlanId] = [s].[PlanId]
    LEFT JOIN [User] AS [u] ON [m].[UserId] = [u].[Id]
    WHERE [m].[MeetingId] = 1
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [Document] AS [m0] ON [t].[MeetingId] = [m0].[MeetingId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [blah]
    FROM [Topic] AS [m1]
    LEFT JOIN [Extra] AS [a] ON [m1].[ExtraId] = [a].[ExtraId]
) AS [t0] ON [t].[MeetingId] = [t0].[MeetingId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [blah]
    FROM [Component] AS [m2]
    LEFT JOIN [Extra] AS [a0] ON [m2].[ExtraId] = [a0].[ExtraId]
) AS [t1] ON [t].[MeetingId] = [t1].[MeetingId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [blah]
    FROM [Recipient] AS [m3]
    INNER JOIN [Info] AS [l] ON [m3].[InfoId] = [l].[InfoId]
) AS [t2] ON [t].[MeetingId] = [t2].[MeetingId]
```

If you look at the last 3 joins, there are no filters so they will scan the whole table.

Is there a way to fix this?

This is EF Core 3.1 btw.

Comment: What filters are you expecting? The `JOIN` itself is a filter, and no more filters are needed in this case. The joining field is FK which usually is indexed, so no full table scans will be performed, but the typical index range scan.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the query execution plan though? How a query is written and how it is executed are seldom the same unless it's some very simple query. The last 3 subqueries have implicit filters because they're part of a join; sqlserver will not naively run the join, generate some million records then scan through them looking for an id; it knows their results will be joined on id, and id is selected, so the id requirement can be pushed down into the inner query as a filter. It's incredibly difficult to defeat this mechanism, even sometimes when you want to..

Comment: *Is there a way to fix this?* - first, make absolutely sure it's a problem. Nothing posted so far proves it is..

Comment: @CaiusJard It actually is a problem. The LINQ got a timeout on this SQL. I am not sure how SQL Server handles it or the execution plan (I am not a db savvy). All I know is: 1. it times out 2. it returns me 7000+ rows which mostly are duplicates.

Comment: @IvanStoev So say the 2nd sub query that joins `Topic` onto `Extra`, I am expecting a `where` that filters `Topic` with the `MeetingId` value.

Comment: But you've obscured the actual query so it's harder to explain. You've reduced every SELECT to [blah] -- the query wasn't like that before otherwise the join would t work. So the inner query selects MeetingId and some other stuff, meetingID is used in the outer query as part of the join, so in simple terms sqlserver can know the meeting id before it runs the inner query because it can see the link through from outer to inner, so it only needs to query the inner query on that id. Run the query and post the actual execution plan so we can see. Check out Brent Ozar's "paste the plan"

Comment: Joins has nothing to do with your issue. The issue is that in order to produce requested result shape having included **collections** with single SQL query, the query must return the union of all the selected table columns plus cartesian product of the records. That's why EFC 5.0 provides [split query mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries), which is how EFC 1/2 was processing such requests. Unfortunately this has been changed in 3.x with no way to control it. The added option in 5.0 is specifically for issues like yours, but with 3.x your are out of luck.

Comment: Since you are materializing the result, remove the last 3 `Include` (and their `ThenInclude`) and use explicit loading after getting the result with other data. This has to be done only for collections.

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for your explanation. There are dozens of select columns in the actual SQL which I think might make it harder to read so have removed them.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you again. I had a look at the split query thing and it looks promising. I might just look at upgrading my 3.1 to 5.0 since 3.1 also has a lot of other limitations.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are not bound to NET Framework (or Net Standard 2.0), converting to 5.0 shouldn't be an issue.